# flex tabnavigator cuts off labels

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have a problem with the `TabNavigator`. The labels of the tabs are getting truncated and once the user places their mouse over the tab it redraws again. Is there anyway to redraw the label of the tab programmatically?

Comment: I have the same problem when I use bindings. If someone has a solution... I'm interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also want to consider the [`SuperTabNavigator`](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/containers/SuperTabNavigator.html) in [FlexLib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [Spark TabBar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TabBar.html) with a ViewStack instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with TabNavigator. It was related to TitleWindow where my TabNavigator was located.

This is cool solution from - [How to Show a Tab Navigator in a Popup Window](http://userflex.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/tab-navigator-popup/)

```
package
{
    import mx.containers.TabNavigator;
    import mx.controls.Button;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    public class PopUpFriendlyTabNavigator extends TabNavigator
    {
        public function PopUpFriendlyTabNavigator()
        {
            super();

            this.addEventListener (FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, onCreationComplete);
        }

        private function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            this.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, onCreationComplete);

            var firstTab:Button = getTabAt(0);

            if (firstTab)
            {
                firstTab.invalidateDisplayList();
                firstTab.validateNow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```